# How to convert safely from char* to string in legacy code?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have the following problem:

```
char * cs = legacy_function();
```

I would refactor it to

```
string s = legacy_function();
```

but I'm guessing that the program "leaks" `cs`. Should I write the following then?

```
char * cs = legacy_function();
string s = cs; 
delete[] cs;
```

Or does std::string have an alternative constructor that doesn't copy cs?

Comment: I would utilize unique_ptr which will do the delete for you.

Comment: Does the current code delete `cs`?

Comment: @AnonMail You are thinking about something like `string s = unique_ptr<char[]>(legacy_function()).get();`?

Comment: No.  I was thinking of something like this: std::unique_ptr<char> cs(legacy_function()); s = cs.get().

Comment: @user2079303 I fixed my comment.

Comment: @AnonMail Why not doing it inline? You could even create a typedef for it...

Comment: Actually, after seeing the answers below, I prefer creating a function wrapper.  It just seems cleaner to the eye.

Comment: Note that if legacy code returns memory allocated with `malloc`, then you have to call `free` instead of `delete[]`.

Comment: AnonMail, Simon Kraemer, Jarod42 thanks for the ideas men!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>

char* legacy_function()
{
    char* a = new char[100];
    memcpy(a, "Hello", 6);
    return a;
}

typedef std::unique_ptr<char[]> legacy_string_convert;

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string s = legacy_string_convert(legacy_function()).get();
    cout << s << endl; 

}
```

Answer (score 4):

> but I'm guessing that the program "leaks" cs. Should I write the following then?

Don't guess. Read the documentation. Or if it's lacking, read the implementation.

If `legacy_function` allocates the string dynamically with `new[]`, then yes, `delete[]` must be called when you no longer need it or else the memory leaks.

> Or does std::string have an alternative constructor that doesn't copy cs?

No, it does not.

Answer (score 1):

> but I'm guessing that the program "leaks" cs. Should I write the
>   following then?

You can't tell that if you don't know whether the legacy function is returning dynamically allocated memory or not.

Answer (score 1):

It will be better to create a layer of functions under a `namespace` and the use the functions from the `namespace` in rest of your code.

```
namespace lagacy_wrapper
{
   std::string legacy_function()
   {
      char * cs = ::legacy_function();
      std::string s = cs; 
      delete[] cs; // You'll need to use free(cs) if memory for cs
                   // was allocated using malloc family of functions.
      return s;
   }
}
```

and use:

```
std::string s = lagacy_wrapper::legacy_function();
```

Comment: @BaummitAugen, I work in a desktop environment and tend to ignore issues like that. Please feel free to edit my answer that addresses the issue.

Comment: Nah, this does not *need* an edit, this was just an (admittedly pedantic for most users) remark since I believe many people are not aware of this potential "danger". My comment is meant as a snippet of bonus information. Besides, there are already three C++11 answers that handle that scenario, might not hurt to leave a C++98 answer around.

Answer (score 1):

> Or does std::string have an alternative constructor that doesn't copy cs?

No, it does not. If `legacy_function` does a dynamic allocation (you should check this of course), you will have to match its `new[]` with a real `delete[]` or let a smart pointer handle it like this:

```
std::string modern_wrapper () {
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> ptr{legacy_function()};
    return std::string(ptr.get());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you sure that returned pointer allocated by `new[]` and you call `legacy_function()` once yes you have to write it with explicit `delete[]`. You may also use `std::unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> cs( legacy_function() );
std::string s = cs.get();
```

but if you have to call `legacy_function()` multiple times, I would put a wrapper that returns `std::string`